Presentation of double categories as algebras for a monad on an inverse category and its virtualisation
This question is motivated by the theory of walking structures and computads. Namely see the end of the linked paragraph on computads over at nlab:

For example, if $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{P}\times \mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{P} = (1 \rightrightarrows 0)$, then there is a monad on $Set^{\mathcal{J}}$ whose algebras are double categories, and in this way we can obtain a notion of “double computad”.

With the silent part being that $\mathcal{J}$ is an inverse category.
Is there a good reference for this claim of presenting double categories?
Is there a similar presentation of virtual double categories as algebras for some monad on $Set^{\mathcal{X}}$ for some inverse category $\mathcal{X}$?
P.S. I would say monadic over copresheaves on an inverse category, which would be a snappier title, but I am not sure if this presentation should extend to a correspondence between double functors and algebra morphisms.
